# How do I get pylons to print the Traceback on the console?

Tags: command-line, pylons, traceback

I'd like to be able to just see any errors on the command line where I'm running paster. Most of my application is AJAX so the interactive debugger doesn't help me most of the time and I'm getting tired of copying the url all the time.

Documentation isn't too clear, so li'l help please.

UPDATE:
Further reading in the doc shows me that it has something to do with the [ErrorHandler middleware](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/modules/middleware/#pylons.middleware.ErrorHandler) which will produce ErrorMiddleware in production and EvalException middleware in dev. What I'm looking for is some way to make the EvalException still emit the traceback rather than just the debug link to the console. I don't want to remove the existing functionality of the interactive debugger. Just have my Traceback and eat it too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, what you need is Paste's `--verbose` option.  Try running it with that and see if the traceback errors show up on the console.  Paste's command-line options [are documented here](http://pythonpaste.org/script/#running-the-server).

As a supplement to that, consider using [the logging module as documented by the Pylons book](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/logging.html) and sprinkling `log.warn("foo")` messages liberally through your Python code to expose its internal state during the chunks of program execution that you're interested in.  Those will show up on the console when you're using `--verbose`, which should help.

Comment: That didn't really work, the exceptions are swallowed by the ErrorHandler middleware, I think the solution involves some sort of config setting that gets passed to that middleware, I don't want to totally take out the interactive debugging but I'd like it to also have the traceback printed.

Comment: What exactly happens, then, when you encounter one of the errors that you'd like to see a traceback for?  Are we talking about JavaScript errors, or Python errors?  Are you using the logging module?

Comment: Sorry this isn't really helping me. I don't have any issues with using the log. Just getting the tracebacks from unexpected exceptions the occur while you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you could try configuring it so that AJAX errors would be shown in the browser in the same way as "normal" errors.. Something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(xhr, errtype, e){
        $("html").html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```